# Why I did not get SAML response of Identity provider , why I am getting SAML response of Service provider with Issuer is localhost

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 Identity server , where I configured ADFS as a Identity Provider with SAML SSO web and ADFS send s some SAML Response , and also I configured ServiceProvider in wso2 Identity server , but while i am heating Consumer application it goes to Identity server and then ADFS and after ADFS credential it come back to Consumer and then goes to API Manager and then goes to Backend application , But in the Back end application I got the SAML Response of Service Provider not the SAML Response of Identity provider ADFS.I am getting SAML response with Issuer as localhost:but I mention Identity provider id in IDP as http://adfs.xyz.com/adfs/trust , so i have to got "http://adfs.xyz.com/adfs/trust" as Issuer why I am getting Issuer as localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is similar to the Usecase2 described in [1]. Since your web app sends the saml request to wso2 IS , it will get the saml response from wso2 IS once it is authenticated via federated authentication(ADFS). So issue will be wso2 IS.

1.http://umeshagunasinghe.blogspot.com/2014/06/use-case-scenarios-with-wso2-identity.html

Comment: ok But I wants in my Backend ADFS SAML response how i will avoid SAML Response of Service Provider

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please follow the image of my usecase

Comment: I don't think so you can get the exact saml response of ADFS,But you can do the claim mapping to get the user attributes in SAML response of wso2 IDP 

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Logging+into+the+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials

Comment: Yes you are correct , I already configure claims of ADFS like email,username etc, and also I am getting also in SAML Response in Backed . But the problem is the exact SAML response of ADFS and what I am getting SAML response in backed is not matching , only the claims of ADFS I am getting , but remaining things is mismatch with SAML Response of ADFS..

Answer (score 0):

If it is the issuer name that matters you, You can change it at `Identity Providers` -> `List` -> `Resident Identity Provider` -> `Inbound Authentication Configuration` -> `SAML2 Web SSO Configuration` -> `Identity Provider Entity Id`

And if you also needs the claims as from the ADFS you'll need to do [claim mapping](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider) as required as suggested by Jenananthan.